# What is the SKU of a motor?

Tags: motor, standard

I came across an 'N20' motor, and I don't know what that means. As far as I can tell (and please correct me if I'm wrong), N20 is the SKU of the motor. What is the SKU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N20 refers to the physical size of the motor.

SKU is a stock keeping unit and has nothing to do with the technical specification of the motor.

Comment: Thanks! Does N20 come from a standard?

Comment: SKU is just an identifier used by the vendor to refer to that particular motor

Comment: And N20? Is it a form factor that comes from a standard?